# Add a product with multiselect custom option to the cart in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using `magento 1.9` version. Doing a functionality to add a product and its' option to the cart programmatically.

I have a product `(id=120)`. Which have a custom option to select the multiple values `( say option=25, and option 27)`. I want to *`add these product and it's custom option to the cart`*.

I know this functionality with `single custom option value`. But here I need to custom values of an option.

Does any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your parameter array, use `array(value_id1,value_id2...)` instead of single value for the option id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is your issue.. I found a simple way of magento to handle a multi selected custom option array to pass to the cart

The standard is an array should always start from 0 index, right ? 
But magento will only take multi select option values array if you start it from index 2.. 
So for example below will work:

> 'options' => array(
>       21 => 58,
>       20 => 55,
>       11 => 28,
>       12 => array(
>           2 => 31,
>       ),
>       13 => array(
>           2 => 32,
>           3 => 35,
>       ), ),

In above example you will see option_id 13 which has multi values passed in an array, which is starting from 2nd index. this worked for me.. i hope it will work for others as well. :)